# Can't paste code in Chrome DevTools

Tags: mac-osx, console, google-chrome

Today, I was trying to run code in the Chrome DevTools console (on macOS). While I was pasting a class-name, I got an error message:

> Warning: Do not paste code into the DevTools console that you do not
> understand or that you have not checked yourself. Such code may allow
> attackers to steal your identity or take over your computer. Type
> {PH1} below to allow pasting.

I tried following the instructions, by typing {PH1} and after that PH1. Both don't work; I have gotten the error message: VM876:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: PH1 is not defined at :1:3

[image: Screenshots with attempts and errors.]

I feel silly for even asking this, but I really don't know; what should I do so that I can execute code in Chrome DevTools again?